# How can I turn an observable into an observable of long polling observables which complete on a specific value?

Tags: javascript, long-polling, rxjs

I'm creating an interactive webpage with RxJs.

This is what I want to achieve:

I have an application that generates tokens. These tokens can be consumed by an external entity.

When a user creates a token, the page starts polling the webserver for its status (consumed or not). When the token is consumed, the page refreshes.

So, when the token is created, a request is sent to the server every 2 seconds asking whether the token is consumed yet.

I have an `Observable` of strings that represent my `generatedTokens`.

I actually already have a working implementation using the Rx.Scheduler.default class, which allows me to do things manually. However, I can't help but feel that there should be a much simpler, more elegant solution to this.

This is the current code:

```
class TokenStore {
  constructor(tokenService, scheduler) {
    // actual implementation omitted for clarity
    this.generatedTokens = Rx.Observable.just(["token1", "token2"]);

    this.consumedTokens = this.generatedTokens
      .flatMap(token => 
        Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
          var notify = function() {
            observer.onNext(token);
            observer.onCompleted();
          };
          var poll = function() {
            scheduler.scheduleWithRelative(2000, function() {
                // tokenService.isTokenConsumed returns a promise that resolves with a boolean
                tokenService.isTokenConsumed(token)
                  .then(isConsumed => isConsumed ? notify() : poll());
              }
            );
          };
          poll();
        }));
  }
}
```

Is there something like a "repeatUntil" method? I'm looking for an implementation that does the same thing as the code above, but looks more like this:

```
class TokenStore {
  constructor(tokenService, scheduler) {
    // actual implementation omitted for clarity
    this.generatedTokens = Rx.Observable.just(["token1", "token2"]);

    this.consumedTokens = this.generatedTokens
      .flatMap(token =>
        Rx.Observable.fromPromise(tokenService.isTokenConsumed(token))
                     .delay(2000, scheduler)
                      // is this possible?
                     .repeatUntil(isConsumed => isConsumed === true));
  }
}
```

Comment: just wondering, why are you implementing long polling. Why not use node.js with socket.io or something?

Comment: We actually started out with SignalR (we're running on a .NET server) but since we ran into some complexity issues and network concerns (our projects are usually deployed inside a DMZ) we're resorting to long polling to decrease complexity and improve testability. SignalR was also a serious hurdle to integration test correctly, and in the end just wasn't worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funnily enough the answer struck me a few minutes after posting the question. I suppose rubberducking might not be so silly after all.

Anyway, the answer consisted of two parts:

- repeatUntil can be achieved with a combination of `repeat()`, `filter()` and `first()`
- `fromPromise` has some internal lazy cache mechanism which causes subsequent subscriptions to NOT fire a new AJAX request. Therefore I had to resort back to using `Rx.Observable.create`

The solution:

```
class TokenStore {
  constructor(tokenService, scheduler) {
    // actual implementation omitted for clarity
    this.generatedTokens = Rx.Observable.just(["token1", "token2"]);

    this.consumedTokens = this.generatedTokens
      .flatMap(token =>
        // must use defer otherwise it doesnt retrigger call upon subscription
        Rx.Observable
        .defer(() => tokenService.isTokenConsumed(token))
        .delay(2000, scheduler)
        .repeat()
        .filter(isConsumed => isConsumed === true)
        .first())
    .share();
  }
}
```

A minor sidenote: the "share()" ensures that both observables are hot, which avoids the scenario where every subscriber would cause ajax request to start firing.

Comment: Note that the first `share()` in this example does nothing. Realistically I get that you are just mocking it, but using it with `just` is pretty much the same and using only `just` but with more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TokenSource {
  constructor(tokenService, scheduler) {
    this.generatedTokens = Rx.Observable.just(["token1", "token2"]).share();

    this.consumedTokens = this.generatedTokens
      .flatMap(token => 
         Rx.Observable.interval(2000, scheduler)
               .flatMap(Rx.Observable.defer(() => 
                          tokenService.isTokenConsumed(token)))
               .first(isConsumed => isConsumed === true))
      .share()

  }
}
```

You can take advantage of two facts:

1. `flatMap` has an overload that takes an observable which will be resubscribed to every time a new event comes in
2. `defer` can take a method returning a promise. The method will be re-executed every subscription, which means you do not have to roll your own `Promise`->`Observable` conversion.

Comment: Am I correcting in stating that this solution will trigger a request every 2 seconds until isConsumed is true? This is different from what I had, which only triggered another request when the previous one had finished. Thanks for the interesting solution though!